# Restrict Elastic Beanstalk server public url to be accessible

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-api-gateway

I set up a Elastic Beanstalk flask server and have a public url. I want to restrict EBS to access publicly but only through API Gateway. 
Can someone help me a simple easy procedure to accomplish this. thank you.

Comment: see https://serverfault.com/questions/698007/launch-instances-via-elastic-beanstalk-without-elastic-ip-configured see the vpc with AssociatePublicIpAddress false. I am not sure if you can do that from console or only fom cli

Answer (score 0):

**Option One - Certificates**

You can generate a self-signed certificate on your API gateway, then give the EBS instance the public key. When your EBS instance is called, your server checks that it has been called by the API gateway (by verifying the certificate).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html

**Option Two - Virtual Private Cloud**

Setup a VPC with your API gateway and EBS instance on a private subnet. Allow public access to the API gateway only.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/vpc.html

Comment: I always end up messing VPC and could not get access.